# How to recognize touch inside SVG object in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, svg, svgkit

I'm currently building an app where I need to recognize a touch point inside a SVG map. So I have a `map` with multiple `rectangles` and when the user touches one of these `rectangles` an action needs to be triggered. How can I solve this?

One option would be to mathematically calculate if the touch location lies in between a rectangle, but I am not a math genius.

My preferred option would be to use a framework. I found the SVGKit framework but unfortunately its written in Objective C.

Comment: You can use SVGKit for a swift project, you'll just need an umbrella file.

Comment: Really? Okay thank youuu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SVGKit for a Swift project. You have to use an **umbrella header file**, it is the 'master' header file for a framework.

> ### Importing Objective-C into Swift
>
> Access classes and other declarations from your Objective-C code in
>   Swift.
>
> **Overview**
>
> You can use Objective-C and Swift files together in a single project,
>   no matter which language the project used originally. This makes
>   creating mixed-language app and framework targets as straightforward
>   as creating an app or framework target written in a single language.
>
> [image]
>
> The process for using your Objective-C declarations from your Swift
>   code within mixed-language targets differs slightly depending on
>   whether you’re writing an app or a framework. Both processes are
>   described below.
>
> **Import Code Within an App Target**
>
> To import a set of Objective-C files into Swift code within the same
>   app target, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header file to expose
>   those files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header when you add
>   a Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to
>   an existing Swift app.
>
> [image]
>
> If you accept, Xcode creates the bridging header file along with the
>   file you were creating, and names it by using your product module name
>   followed by "-Bridging-Header.h". Alternatively, you can create a
>   bridging header yourself by choosing `File` > `New` > `File` >
>   `[operating system]` > `Source` > `Header File`.
>
> Edit the bridging header to expose your Objective-C code to your Swift
>   code:
>
> - In your Objective-C bridging header, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift.
> - In Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting has a path to the
>     bridging header file. The path should be relative to your project,
>     similar to the way your `Info.plist` path is specified in Build
>     Settings. In most cases, you won't need to modify this setting.
>
> Any public Objective-C headers listed in the bridging header are
>   visible to Swift. The Objective-C declarations are automatically
>   available from any Swift file within that target, with no import
>   statements. Use classes and other declarations from your custom
>   Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use for system
>   classes.
>
> **Import Code Within a Framework Target**
>
> To use the Objective-C declarations in files in the same framework
>   target as your Swift code, you’ll need to import those files into the
>   Objective-C umbrella header—the master header for your framework.
>   Import your Objective-C files by configuring the umbrella header:
>
> - Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for the framework target is set to `Yes`.
> - In the umbrella header, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift.
>
> Swift sees every header you expose publicly in your umbrella header.
>   The contents of the Objective-C files in that framework are
>   automatically available from any Swift file within that framework
>   target, with no import statements. Use classes and other declarations
>   from your Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use for
>   system classes.
>
> **[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)**

**Additional information**

- **[How to include Objective-C frameworks in your Swift project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html)**